# How make a MainActor Observable class adhere to the Codable protocol?

Tags: swift, swiftui

In the following example class:

```
@MainActor
class Person: ObservableObject, Codable {
    @Published var name: String
    
    init(name: String) {
        self.name = name
    }
    
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name
    }
    
    required init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
    }
    
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        try container.encode(name, forKey: .name)
    }
}
```

There are two similar warnings on the init/encode methods:

> Initializer 'init(from:)' isolated to global actor 'MainActor' can not satisfy corresponding requirement from protocol 'Decodable'

> Instance method 'encode(to:)' isolated to global actor 'MainActor' can not satisfy corresponding requirement from protocol 'Encodable'

Making these methods `async` generates two errors:

> Type 'Person' does not conform to protocol 'Decodable'

> Type 'Person' does not conform to protocol 'Encodable'

I noticed, however, that making them `async` fixes the errors/warnings IF the class does not have a published property. So re-defining `name` as following:

```
var name: String
```

and the two methods to be `async`:

```
required init(from decoder: Decoder) async throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    name = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .name)
}

func encode(to encoder: Encoder) async throws {
    var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    try container.encode(name, forKey: .name)
}
```

Generates no errors/warnings.

Why do we get errors if the property is published? Is there a way to get rid of the warnings/errors if we want the property to stay `@Published`?

Using the latest Xcode: Version 13.3 (13E113)

Comment: Is it really necessary to make your model object both a MainActor and conforming to Codable and being an ObservableObject? Why can this class only be modified on the main thread? Maybe you would be helped by splitting functionality between different types? For instance when using MVVM then typically the view model would conform to ObservableObject while the model would conform to Codable.

Comment: @JoakimDanielson having it conform to Observable is because of SwiftUI, and Codable is needed so it can be sent over between the phone and watch. There is surely room for refactoring in my case but was wondering if there was a way to fix this before starting. Thanks.

Comment: I don’t know that it is written anywhere but actors aren’t data models they are more where you do stuff with the data models.

Comment: @loremipsum that's a good point. I don't think I've read this before but it does make sense.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest making your model stuff pure value type Structs/Enums and your observed object, your app state, be a reference type (Class)

```
struct Person: Codable {
    var name: String
}

@MainActor
class AppState: ObservableObject {
    @Published var person: Person
}
```

Comment: Great answer! Apple provide info on the benefits of structs here: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/choosing_between_structures_and_classes

Comment: Thanks but I'd rather know the reason/resolution for issue before I refactor the code.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you are applying `MainActor` attribute to anything swift ensures that all the access to properties and methods are synchronized and when you try to access a property or method from a different actor you have to add `await` to the call.

When you are implementing `Codable` to a type isolated to `MainActor`, the implementations can only be invoked from the same actor, i.e. only from the same actor you can use `encode(to:)` or you have to use `await encode(to:)` when calling from the different actor. To properly satisfy `Codable` requirements you have to add `nonisolated` specifier to method implementations.

The major place you will be using `Codable` implementations is from your networking code, instead of bringing your networking code isolated `MainActor` separate your codable model and view model:

```swift
struct Person: Codable {
    var name: String
}

@MainActor
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var person: Person
}
```